# Loading tidyverse on mac

Tags: r, tidyverse, rcpp

I'm trying to load tidyverse, but it's not working

```
 install.packages("tidyverse")

tentando a URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.6/tidyverse_1.3.0.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 433010 bytes (422 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 422 KB


The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/0y/ws5t3y7d5_j2wbz47ds47ckc0000gn/T//RtmpPIo9hy/downloaded_packages



     library(tidyverse)

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘Rcpp’
```

I tried to install Rcpp

```
    install.packages("Rcpp")

1 error generated.
make: *** [api.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Rcpp’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/Rcpp’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘Rcpp’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/0y/ws5t3y7d5_j2wbz47ds47ckc0000gn/T/RtmpPIo9hy/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: Normally, `api.o` is not the first object compiled, is there any intermediate text that you've omitted to try to reduce the question size? Just by the nature that this is your first foray into R, do you have macos `xcode` installed? If it's been installed a while, can you update it and try again? (If there is more error text, please include that, too.)

Comment: Apparently there is still no R 3.6.* binary of `Rcpp` version 1.0.4.6 at CRAN and its mirrors. A volunteer got in contact with me today so we may have a binary at the `drat` repo for `Rcpp` at some point.